# From where hasRole from @PreAuthorize take its values in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Hi I am new to Spring and I am trying to understand the security model a little more.
In our project we controller which method is annotated with

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('REPORT_VIEW')")
```

So I am wondering from where this `REPORT_VIEW` comes from is it ENUM or is based on some xml configuration? I search in the files but I can't find `REPORT_VIEW` as word.

From here:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-access-control-example/

I saw that there is configuration security-context.xml  where

```
<user-service>
        <user name="mkyong" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        <user name="eclipse" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</user-service>
```

In my project

```
<sec:authentication-manager>
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>
```

So I as developer who wants to create some controller from where to understand which are the roles for the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can explain you via XML files and some Java code. Here is how I do login and assign the role. You can also query the DB for roles.

security-applicationContext.xml :

```
 <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginServiceImpl">
           <security:password-encoder  ref="encoder"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
                class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
                <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
               <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

Above is my DB authentication code, which referes to the bean of LoginServiceImpl, from where I am searching the user in DB. the model class has implemented UserDetails.

LoginServiceImpl :

```
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private PersonDAO personDAO;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException,DataAccessException {
        Person person = personDAO.findPersonByUsername(username.toLowerCase());
            if(person == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");}
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(person);
    }

    public LoginServiceImpl() {
    }
}
```

When the the user is found in the DB, I am constructing an Object which can be used by spring-security for the session and all. This is how it goes :

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(Person userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername().toLowerCase();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();

        boolean enabled = userEntity.isEnabled();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        return new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        }
}
```

As you can see, I am adding the role, but I can also query the DB, or any other logic which you find, and then hand it over and the user will have that role. Ideally, Person model class should have one-to-many mapping to Role class, and the users roles inside it. 
If this is not what you are looking for, I will delete my answer, just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The functionality of spring security is not so trivial, but I try to explain:

Spring security authentication is based on `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` which is the spring abstraction of an user. A `UserDetails` has `GrantedAuthority`s which can be permissions, roles or any other "SecurityItem" of your application. The `hasRole` checks if the current user has a `GrantedAuthority` with the name in the Expression (e.g. 'REPORT_VIEW').

But where do these `UserDetails` come from. This depends on your application. The are provided by a class implementing `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`. This is where the specific user store of your application hooks in. Spring provides a couple of alreay implemented `UserDetailsService` but you can implement your own, too (e.g. if you store your user credentials in a custom database).

In the example you linked, the `UserDetailsService` is created and configured XML based (the simplest variant). In your application the `UserDetails` are provided via OAuth2 and where this is, is defined in a bean called `clientDetails` which you didn't provide.